# How to solve Http POST 403 (Forbidden) in Ionic 2

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I am Beginner in Ionic 2. I want to make user registration from the app .For user registration, i am using API which METHOD is POST and its media type is x-www-form-urlencoded. I want to send data to the server .

But when I am trying using   **IONIC serve** its worked fine on the web browser but when I am trying to send data from actual device its give me **403 forbidden error**

This is my code

```
 doLogins() {
 this.loading = this.loadingController.create({content : "Registering user ..."});
      this.loading.present()
      var url = 'http://services/Registration';

      var officername = this.data.username.trim();
        var officenmae = this.data.office.trim();
        var emal=this.data.email.trim();
        var mobileno=this.data.contact.trim();
        var areode =this.data.areacode;

        var lanlineno=this.data.telno.trim();
        var desgnation= this.data.designation.trim();
        var password=this.data.password.trim();
        var status='A'


     var headers = new Headers()
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

       headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
       headers.append('X-HTTP-Method-Override', 'POST');
       headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-
     let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });



    let body =  "officname=" +offername + "&emiled=" + email + "&mobilenumber=" + mobileno + "&password=" + password + "&offiname=" + officenmae + 
    "&designation=" + designation +"&landnecode=" + areaode +"&landlinnumber=" + lanlineno +"&status=" + 'A';


           return new Promise(resolve => {
            this.http.post(url, body, options) .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
                           data => {
                             console.log(data);

                             let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                              message: "Registration Success",
                              duration: 3000,
                              position: 'top'
                            });
                            toast.present();
                            setTimeout(() => {
                              this.loading.dismissAll();
                              this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage,{
                                param1: email, param2: password
                            });;
                            }, 2500);

                           },
                           err => {
                             alert(err);
                             this.loading.dismissAll();
                           }
                       );  
         });        
      }
```

Please Suggest me where I am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: Looks you are in different network when testing in device.

Comment: yes i am using same network

Comment: 403 Forbidden error is coming from your server (http://services/Registration) but I don't see any server code here. You set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in your request but it should be set only at the response from the server.

Comment: its working on web **Ionic Serve** perfectly then i think  its not a server issue @gaborp

Comment: Then try to access services/Registration from ANY other device than your local computer (for example use another computer with ionic serve), and I think you will not get the response you are waiting for...

Comment: yes , i am getting 403 for mobile

Answer (score 0):

Create on your **server**, in the root of requested URL, a ".htaccess" file with this content:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type"
```